# Error: the declared type of navigation property is not compatible with the result

Tags: entity-framework

This error just makes no sense to me.  I've read the various answers on here and other places - nothing is clicking for me.

> the declared type of navigation property 'Invoice.LineItems' is not compatible with the result of the specified navigation

I have two tables: `Invoices` and `LineItems`.
In their simplest form they look like:

**Invoices**
InvoiceID

**LineItems**
InvoiceID
Name
QTY

and the entities:

```
Public Class Invoice
    <Key>
    Public Property InvoiceID As Int64

    Public Overridable Property LineItems As List(Of LineItem) = New List(Of LineItem)
End Class


Public Class LineItem
    <Key>
    Public Property InvoiceID As Int64

    Public Property Name As String

    Public Property QTY As Int32 = 0
End Class
```

When attempting to fetch Invoices with their associated LineItems, I get the error above.

```
Using database As PosDatabase = New PosDatabase
    Dim invoices As List(Of Invoice) = database.Invoices _
        .Include("LineItems") _
        .ToList()
End Using
```

This is EF 6.2.0

Any help in resolving the issue would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a typo here: `(...) As List(Of LineItem) = New List(Of LineItem)` or here: `Public Class LineItems`

Comment: @Jimi: I corrected that in the question.  Thanks.  Typed the question by hand and that snuck in.  There's no typos in the actual code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception is caused by the improper model mapping.

The FK `InvoiceID` property of the `LineItem` is marked as PK, thus effectively making the relationship 1 to 0..1, i.e. changing the expected multiplicity of the relationship represented by the `LineItems` collection navigation property from `Many` to `One`.

I guess this is just a mapping mistake, the actual PK of the `LineItem` should be different - either own identity column like `LineItemID` or composite PK on `(InvoiceID, Name)`.

So simply map the correct PK (with data annotations or fluent API) of the `LineItem` and the problem will be solved. In my test I did it with

```
modelBuilder.Entity<LineItem>()
    .HasKey(e => new { e.InvoiceID, e.Name });
```

Comment: Ah.  I see.  Is there any other solution?  I ask because the LineItems table does not have a proper PK, just the InvoiceID FK.  I'm writing software that integrates with a POS from another company - so modifying the POS database is out of the question.   I suppose, since in my specific scenario I only need to read the data, I could mark Invoice.LinesItems as NotMapped, then query LineItems separately, and manually associate them with Invoices.  Kind of reduces the value of using an ORM though.

Comment: You are welcome :) Unfortunately there is no other "out of the box" EF way. EF requires PK. If you are just reading, it doesn't need to be real, but has to be something - you could mark all the fields as being a composite PK and hope that there is no duplicate combination. If that doesn't work, then yes, reading the LineItems manually is the only option.